# JavaScript function not returning array as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a json array and a simple function to return a bit of data. I can log the bit of data I want to the console (the function currently does this for testing), but it's not returning.

Stackers, please help my worn out brain and let me know where I've goofed.

(code is super self explanatory, function call is at the bottom of the .js)

http://jsfiddle.net/BDJeU/

```
function getCountryData(data, country)
{
    $.each(data, function(index) {

        if( data[index]["Country"] == country )
        {
            console.log( data[index]["Country"] );
            console.log( data[index]["data"] );
            return data[index]["data"];
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/BDJeU/3/

```
    function getCountryData(data, country)
    {
        var returnData;
        $.each(data, function(index) {

            if( data[index]["Country"] == country )
            {
                returnData = data[index]["data"];
                return false;
            }
        });
        return returnData;
    }
```

The reason the it wasn't working was because you were returning to the `each` function. So setting a variable that gets assigned the value outside of the iteration will get you the data you want.

Comment: @Greg-J No worries. I have definitely had those moments where the answer is starring me in the face.

Answer (score 1):

[`$.grep()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) could be better in this case: http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/BDJeU/12/

```
function getCountryData(data, country)
{
    var result = $.grep(data, function(item) {
        return item["Country"] == country;
    });

    return result && result[0] && result[0]['data'];
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't seen this function in jQuery before this. Good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your return is inside the anonymous function used by `each`. So `getCountryData` itself has no return (so defaults to returning undefined). It needs to be something like this:

```
function getCountryData(data, country)
{
    var result;
    $.each(data, function(index) {

        if( data[index]["Country"] == country )
        {
            console.log( data[index]["Country"] );
            console.log( data[index]["data"] );
            result = data[index]["data"];
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return outside `each` and use `return` to break early out of the `each` iteration:

```
function getCountryData(data, country)
    {
        var res;
        $.each(data, function(index) {

            if( data[index]["Country"] == country )
            {
                res = data[index]["data"];

                // once found, stop searching and
                // break early out of the each iteration                  
                return; 
            }
        });
        return res;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Should you really be using each? if you are trying to filter the results to a single answer try

```
function getCountryData(data, country) {
    var matchingCountries = $.grep(data, function(row){
        return row.Country == country;
    });
    if (matchingCountries.length > 0)
        return matchingCountries[0].data;
}
```